# How to render all values of a container axis?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a chart with a container axis containing many values. It seems to me that I have to define the height of the graph with the CSS attributes. But I do not know the height. When my prediction of the height is too small, some labels get dropped. I want to avoid this. No label should be dropped. How can I calculate the required height?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Root Login Attempts'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data : [
["61.174.51.231",857],
["1.93.32.212",706],
["61.174.51.209",611],
["61.174.51.220",326],
["122.225.109.99",302],
["122.225.109.216",269],
["122.225.109.221",267],
["61.167.49.135",251],
["223.203.195.90",213],
["122.225.109.104",205],
["122.225.109.102",199],
["122.225.109.111",182],
["122.225.109.109",181],
["122.225.109.107",172],
["144.0.0.51",158],
["122.225.109.115",157],
["122.225.109.222",157],
["61.174.51.198",149],
["61.174.51.194",146],
["61.174.51.205",142],
["122.225.109.117",139],
["122.225.109.105",129],
["122.225.109.110",122],
["61.174.51.219",117],
["122.225.109.213",115],
["122.225.109.206",114],
["183.63.52.30",105],
["122.225.109.203",101],
["61.174.51.204",79],
["122.225.109.208",69],
["23.102.67.210",58],
["122.225.109.201",52],
["192.69.94.98",26],
["122.70.133.245",16],
["122.225.109.200",10],
["94.247.101.107",7],
["58.18.172.171",6],
["58.83.146.252",5],
["189.203.240.73",4],
["193.104.41.201",4],
["61.133.211.118",2],
["222.186.21.38",1],
["59.173.13.72",1],
["65.181.118.16",1],
["125.65.245.146",1],
["139.0.12.151",1]
]
        }]
    };

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

System can handle dynamic height resizing when you use CSS as :

```
  #container {
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       position:absolute;
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avqdu1x7/1/

Comment: It is no option to use 100% because even 100% is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add `step: 1` option for labels. That force displaying them all. Now the only problem is with overlapping labels. In that case, just get number of points to be displayed, multiply them by ~20px (each category) and add some extra padding for title and bottom padding (let's say 100px). Now you have height which can be used as `chart.height` option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Root Login Attempts'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: { step: 1 } //added step
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data : [
["61.174.51.231",857],
["1.93.32.212",706],
["61.174.51.209",611],
["61.174.51.220",326],
["122.225.109.99",302],
["122.225.109.216",269],
["122.225.109.221",267],
["61.167.49.135",251],
["223.203.195.90",213],
["122.225.109.104",205],
["122.225.109.102",199],
["122.225.109.111",182],
["122.225.109.109",181],
["122.225.109.107",172],
["144.0.0.51",158],
["122.225.109.115",157],
["122.225.109.222",157],
["61.174.51.198",149],
["61.174.51.194",146],
["61.174.51.205",142],
["122.225.109.117",139],
["122.225.109.105",129],
["122.225.109.110",122],
["61.174.51.219",117],
["122.225.109.213",115],
["122.225.109.206",114],
["183.63.52.30",105],
["122.225.109.203",101],
["61.174.51.204",79],
["122.225.109.208",69],
["23.102.67.210",58],
["122.225.109.201",52],
["192.69.94.98",26],
["122.70.133.245",16],
["122.225.109.200",10],
["94.247.101.107",7],
["58.18.172.171",6],
["58.83.146.252",5],
["189.203.240.73",4],
["193.104.41.201",4],
["61.133.211.118",2],
["222.186.21.38",1],
["59.173.13.72",1],
["65.181.118.16",1],
["125.65.245.146",1],
["139.0.12.151",1]
]
        }]
    };

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
```